# Vue Filtering and Pagination

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, html-table, axios

How can you render a certain number of array objects based on a selected number say 10 or 15 or 25 in Vue pagination ? I have tried rendering 10 items per page and it's working well.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a computed property that slices your array, and use this computed property when iterating the array with `v-for`:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Foo' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Bar' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Baz' }
    ],
    amountOfItemsShown: 2,
  },
  computed: {
    slicedItems() {
      return this.items.slice(0, this.amountOfItemsShown);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  
  <p>Amount of items shown: <input type="range" :min="1" :max="3" v-model="amountOfItemsShown"> <strong>{{ amountOfItemsShown }}</strong></p>
  <div v-for="item in slicedItems" :key="item.id">
    {{ item.name }}
  </div>
</div>
```